# Page is unclickable after closing a window

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My flow is as follows in selenium:

1. Access a webpage
2. Click a tab
3. Click on add button in a tab where a window would open
4. Close that window
5. Click on that same tab again

I'm able to go through steps 1 to 4 without issues however at step 5 i'm not able to click the tab element knowing that i've clicked that same tab at  step2, I did check from console and the same xpath I used in step2 did not return any element however when i clicked on that element to inspect it in console it started returning some values in console but still didn't work from selenium when i continued the run (in debug)
My page is in an Iframe which i was successfully able to access and print page title after step 4 but my issue remains, why aren't i able to click that tab from selenium after i close the window and the screen refreshes, why are the elements unresponsive anymore?
After doing some research i also tried the below script:

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath(the_path));
JavascriptExecutor  ex=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
ex.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", element);
```

but it would fail at the first line since the element is not fount, tried to initialize it earlier in the code but then it would fail at line 3.
How do i fix this issue?

Comment: Once you close the window in the step 4, are you not switching back to the main window again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to having multiple Iframes in the main page, so when closing switching windows I was not redirected to the proper Iframe in which i was in step 3 when clicking the tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try to click on the element using Selenium code, not by injecting JavaScript to the pages. This should solve your problem.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(the_path));
element.click();
```